# 800a0ad error in VBS, Windows 7 32

Tags: windows-7, atl, wsh, ole-automation

I wrote a simple ActiveX Dll object with C++ & ATL (VS2010) for using in VBS scripting engine embedded in a SCADA system. It's just a code carcass now, just interfaces with stubs, no dependencies. Every interface designed to be called from client side have dual interface. 
I can see this object from OLE/COM Object Viewer and can instantiate it from there. I've got no problem with instantiating this ActiveX object using C#'s interop services for debug purposes.

However, when i'm trying to instantiate this from wscript (vbs) I get this 800a0ad error.

The operating system is Windows 7 (32 bit), not x64.

Comment: You posted wrong error code, is it `0x800a00ad`? Which MSDN suggests to be `ERR_INVALIDTYPE_RDNATTR` "The profile-property is marked as an RDN-attribute, but is not of type 'STRING'."